# Eclipse RCP: Required plugin could not be found

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to Eclipse RCP and plugin development so please don't be cruel.

I am using Maven and I have a remote repository. Yesterday Eclipse was fine but today it got messed up and I imported all the projects again so I reconfigured all but I can't get out of this problem. We use e(fx)clipse 2.5 but I installed the 3.0 version of it because I didn't find the link to install it via Eclipse.

Could you please tell me how I add a dependency? There is something that I am missing there?

[image: image of the error output in Eclipse RCP]

Thank you

Comment: Does adding the location `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7` to your target platform fix the errors?

Comment: Thank you. Not all the errors. I still need: javax.xml, org.apache.xerces, org.apache.xml.resolver, org.apache.xml.serializer

Comment: Now only org.apache.xerces, org.apache.xml.resolver, org.apache.xml.serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the location `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/` to your target platform should fix the errors.